# Can't load separate controller model file into modular sinatra app

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

Currently I'm using same method steal from [sinatra-boilerplate](https://github.com/rziehl/sinatra-boilerplate), which works fine. But it's in classic style, I want change it modular style. So I was trying to apply same require technique:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base    
    Dir["./App/Controllers/*.rb", "./App/Models/*.rb", "./App/Helpers/*.rb"].each {|file| require file}                                                                                       
end
```

And a screenshot of my file structure 
[image]

after I run `backup`, and try to access any controller route, I got an 404 page, it turns out all the controller load into `main scope`, instead of the class definition of `MyApp`.

Should I use something like:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
   load("magic_file.rb", false, binding)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the modular style, you still have to "use" your controller classes. Something like:

```
require 'sinatra'
Dir["./App/Controllers/*.rb", "./App/Models/*.rb", "./App/Helpers/*.rb"].each {|file| require file} 

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base    
    use MyController1
    use MyController2                                                                                 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you `require` or `load` the files or the namespace they were called from, it matters what is *in* the files. The easiest way to do this is to open the files and add the namespace to them. Personally, I have mine pre wrapped but with `APP_NAME` instead of the name I want, and then I run a find and replace over the project to rename it. I don't know how you'd do it meta style.